# Two buttons multiple toggle elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have multiple tables displaying toggle content, with one button its OK, but I want to use to buttons to do the same thing, but if I click on button one I want to change class for first button and second button, also when you click on second button to toggle element I want change class for both buttons.

```
$('.triggerNew,.triggerInfo').click(function() {   
  var Itemid = $('#Itemid').val();   
  var text = $(this).text();   
  var id = $(this).attr('id');   
  var lijn = 'tr#' + 'lijn' + $(this).attr('id');   
  var extra = 'tr#' + 'extra' + $(this).attr('id');   
  var result = '#result' + $(this).attr('id');   
  var triggerNew = $(".triggerNew");

  $('.triggerNew').text($(this).text() == '[-]' ? '[+]' : '[-]');
  $('.triggerInfo').text($(this).text() == 'infonew' ? 'info' : 'infonew'); 

  if(text == '[+]' || text == 'info') {
    $("<tr id=\"extra" + id + "\"><td colspan=\"5\"><div id=\"result" + $(this).attr('id') + "\"><div class=\"block\" style=\"text-align:center;padding:10px 0 10px 0;\"><img src=\"img/ajax-loader.gif\" /></div></div></td></tr>").insertAfter(lijn);

    $(extra).hide();
    $(extra).slideDown('slow');
    $(result).load(rooturl+'#' + id + '&Itemid=' + Itemid);
    $(this).removeClass('yescondext').addClass('nocondtext');

    return false;
  } else {
    $(extra).slideUp('slow');
    $(result).remove();
    $(this).removeClass('nocondtext').addClass('yescondext');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Can any one help me please

all code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/QKyYS/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WSwJe/embedded/result/) is what you have in mind.

How to achieve it:

```
$(this).closest('td').find(".triggerNew").text( $(this).closest('td').find(".triggerNew").text() == '[-]' ? '[+]' : '[-]' );
$(this).closest('td').find(".triggerInfo").text( $(this).closest('td').find(".triggerInfo").text() == 'infonew' ? 'info' : 'infonew' );
```

should be there, just after the `$(result).load(rooturl + '#' + id + '&Itemid=' + Itemid);` call.

Also, in the `else` block

```
$(this).closest('td').find(".triggerNew").text( $(this).closest('td').find(".triggerNew").text() == '[-]' ? '[+]' : '[-]' );
$(this).closest('td').find(".triggerInfo").text( $(this).closest('td').find(".triggerNew").text() != 'infonew' ? 'info' : 'infonew' );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSwJe/) link again.

Comment: but i also have line after   

`$(this).removeClass('nocondtext').addClass('yescondext');`   

and i want to add that class to those 2 elelements and remove as well

Comment: @user2140670 Replace the `$(this)` with `$(this).closest('td').find(".triggerNew, .triggerInfo")`

Comment: @user2140670 You can select the answer to close this question. Otherwise it'll pop-up in the unanswered questions listing.

Comment: i've antother question what if they not in the same 'td' can i user 'tr' instead

`$j(this).closest('tr').find(".triggerNew").text($j(this).closest('tr').find(".triggerNew").text() == '[-]' ? '[+]' : '[-]');  
 $j(this).closest('tr').find(".triggerInfo").text($j(this).closest('tr').find(".triggerNew").text() != 'infonew' ? 'info' : 'infonew');  
 $j(this).closest('tr').find(".triggerNew").removeClass('nocondtext').addClass('yescondext');`

$j is my production markup

Comment: There should be the same parent for all such queries. Yeah, `tr` should work too.